# how to push my object of array into MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I had a .txt file full of names, I got the data, I turned it into an object of array.

Now I need to push my array into MongoDB but I don't know how to do it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUiK5.png)

Comment: Here's a short tutorial on how to save data into your MongoDB database: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_insert.asp

You also might want to look into using the Mongoose library for an easier MongoDB interface.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots. Use formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the database and then use `collection.insertOne()` or `collection.insertMany()` to add the names to your collection.